# How to set a goal in Content hub

Tags: reporting, content-hub

In Sitecore, we can set a goal when a user downloads a media item.
Is it possible OOB to do the same in Content Hub?

There is no Sitecore integration for this project, just the Content Hub.

This is to capture analytics data for marketing, say how often an image has been viewed/downloaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some reporting events that get initiated automatically in the Content Hub. For example, you will be interested in an `asset.download.completed` event.
Whenever an asset is downloaded, a log entry with the `event_type` `asset.download.completed` will be recorded in reporting index.

The full list of reporting events see [here](https://docs.stylelabs.com/contenthub/4.2.x/content/user-documentation/manage/reporting/reporting-events.html).

Then you can view the triggered events in the Reports section. Some tweaks of the reporting filters & dimensions might be required before you will see the expected result.

For external integration, you can query the audit indexes through [Audit REST API](https://docs.stylelabs.com/contenthub/4.2.x/content/integrations/rest-api/audit/endpoints.html?rp=true#business-query) to fetch the captured events as follows:

```
GET /api/audit/business/query{/entityId}{?logType*,raw,from,to,fullText,skip,take,sort,order}
```

Comment: If the user is downloading the asset from a website and not from Content Hub, can we still achieve this.

Comment: Reporting events take place in Sitecore Content Hub only and are captured in the reporting index. Audit API provides only GET endpoints, so you can't write yourself to the reporting index on demand. Suggest to consider GTM for the custom event tracking on a website decoupled from Sitecore or Sitecore Content Hub.